# JS load order of Gmaps4Rails in rails 3.2 using asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

I've been trying to get gmaps4rails working for hours.  I think it's the load order, I even tried cloning a demo app using rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3-- still showing a blank map with no markers.  My JSON is correct from the model.

Project:
https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

**-- application.html.erb (bootstrapped)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**-- Gemfile**

```
gem "gmaps4rails", "~> 1.4.8"
```

**-- Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps
//= require_tree .
```

**-- user.rb**

acts_as_gmappable

def gmaps4rails_address
      "#{self.address}, #{self.city}"
  end

**-- schema**

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.boolean  "gmaps"
  end
```

**-- UsersController**

```
 def index
    @bars = User.all
    @json = User.all.to_gmaps4railsrespond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @users }
end
```

end

**-- my view **

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
<%= @json %>
```

**-- my json printed from the view **

```
[{"lat":37.7381599,"lng":-122.3803166},{"lat":37.5121003,"lng":-122.2009814},{"lat":33.9964092,"lng":-118.4725106}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to read you wasted time: it's not the purpose of my gem :)

I don't see `yield :scripts` in your layout. It's one of the mandatory prerequisites stated in the project's homepage.

Answer (score 0):

put the yield :scripts in your controller view and the <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> before that. ( e.g. put it in the header of your application.html.erb )

Hope it helps. I was pulling my hair on this for an hour ...